# Create a function from value of a custom tag attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, eval

Given an element:

```
<div id='adiv' customAttr='myFuncToExecute'></div>
```

What would be the best way to read the custom attribute, and convert it into an executable method in JavaScript.  I am currently using the `new Function()` constructor:

```
if ($('#adiv').attr('customAttr')) {
    var myFuncV1 = new Function('return ' + $('#adiv').attr('customAttr') + '()');
    var myFuncV2 = new Function($('#adiv').attr('customAttr'));
}
```

`myFuncV1` would be executable as `myFuncV1()`. Alternatively, I am able to use `myFuncV2` in event handler bindings:

```
$('#adifferentdiv').click(myFuncV2);
```

This does work for what I need, but using the `new Function()` constructor is equivalent to using `eval()`.

**The Question:**  Is there a better approach to take for reading and evaluating (no pun intended) custom attributes that contain the name of methods that are to be used elsewhere in a script?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the methods properties of an object, then you can remove the *new Function* approach:

```
var obj = {someMethod: function(){...}};

obj[$('#adiv').attr('customAttr')]();
```

though you might want to test that `obj[$('#adiv').attr('customAttr')]` exists before calling it, e.g.

```
var fn = obj[$('#adiv').attr('customAttr')];

if (fn) fn();
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm pretty sure this is exactly what I am looking for. A quick side-question: Is there a way to do this where the method will accept parameters? I assume the same thing: `var obj = {someMethod: function (param1, param2) { ... }};` ?

Comment: Where *param1* is a string that represents the name of a non–global variable, no. You can use strings with square bracket notation to access named properties of objects, that's it. Global variables are a special case as they are made properties of the global (window in a browser) object. There is no equivalent for other variables (since the "variable object" or [*environment record*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.2.1) of a function execution context can't be accessed directly).